# When are the moderators / is the site active?

Tags: support, election, moderators

I encounter a delay in the review of flags when it's morning here in the Netherlands, let's say 6:00 UTC. That made me wonder what the timezones of the moderators are.

Other sites use this information when electing new moderators, so I thought I could give it a meta question.

Of course, this data is little useful when not compared to the activity of the whole site, so I'd like to see activity stats of the whole site as well.

Comment: Holy crap, my shift was done 5 hours ago, I am going to bed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Moderators

I took the locations of the profile pages<sup>1</sup>:

- [clabacchio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/7348/clabacchio) - Pesaro, Italy - UTC+1
- [Kevin Vermeer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/857/kevin-vermeer) - Grand Rapids, MI - UTC-5
- [Kortuk](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/230/kortuk) - Oklahoma - UTC-6
- [markrages](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/411/markrages) - US - unknown
- [W5VO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/638/w5vo) - Arkansas - UTC-6

> <sup>1: I hope I don't mess with privacy, that was (and is and will be) never the intention. I thought I could list the information as it was freely available on the [moderators tab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) of the users list.</sup>

To give some graphical impression, I made this. I estimated one usually is online from ~8:00 am to ~8:00 pm local time. But as that assumption probably isn't right at all, the image is only a "[shadow of reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave)":

[image]

## All users

I made [a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/106848?LastMonths=1#graph) for this. For the last month, the site seems to be the most active from 14:00 to 20:00. *I* think *this is UTC, but I'm not sure.*

[image]

The last 10 months give a smoother view:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, well, I was bored. Perhaps someone finds it useful.

Comment: The bulk of the peak corresponds to 9:00-17:00 (9:00am to 5:00pm for those who insists on clocks that don't match their planet) eastern daylight time here in the US, which is roughly the east coast of the US and the eastern industrial part of Canada. We are currently UTC-4. In the winter it becomes eastern standard time and is UTC-5.

Comment: Mark is in the US also, but I forget the timezone also ;)

Comment: @Kortuk thanks, edited that in :)

Comment: Don't let Tony see this

Comment: When we are active is the only part here that is going to be very hard for you to determine. I used to be on a rotating shift, but I currently am awake and at work by 8am at latest while W5V0 is often up much later and such. the coverage is probably a little better then that makes it look. I do think someone in the asian area being a mod would be nice, but we will have to wait for someone interested and qualified at an election.

Comment: @Kortuk yeah, it was just based on assumptions. I edited an extra note in for that, thanks for pointing it out. I by the way in no way mean there should be elections, everything's going great (for what I can see, in my opinion)!

Comment: @CamilStaps if you dont think there are enough mods feel free to say so, we dont take offense. The moderator team saying that is how we get more moderators.

Comment: @Kortuk absolutely not! I just wondered :)